# How to give app choices before opening links to facebook, twitter and google plus

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

I am designing a website. I have links - “follow us on facebook”,” follow us on twitter “and “follow us on google plus” .

**On mobiles some users use browser for facebook, others some facebook app. Is there any way that I can give them a choice between browser and the facebook apps they have installed?**

***For example*** if a user have facebook native app and facebook lite installed, on clicking the follow on facebook link he gets choice between browser, facebook app and facebook lite.

I also want similar solutions for twitter and google plus.

**Thanks  thanks thanks for your help and support.**

Comment: I believe Facebook will always send you to the app, if installed.

Comment: no, atleast not in android. i have tried it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Android will open the URLs directly with the app, if your url looks like this: "https://facebook.com/page" or this "fb://page/mypage". 
You can try the URL "m.facebook.com/page", I think most likely this will let the users choose to open the link with the browser.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the device itself determines whether it will open it with the browser or app, your links can't decide how they will be opened.

Comment: I don't think so, sorry.